# Problems with network in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, vlc

I have been trying to reproduce (in other machine in the same network) the video played by this container on the docker-compose via swarm.

```
services:
        vlc:
                image: boydachina/vlc-server
                ports: 
                        - 8080:8080
                        - 8554:8554
                networks:
                        - vlc_net
                command:
                        - cvlc -vvv /opt/vlc-media/python.mp4 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}'        
                volumes:
                        - ./media:/opt/vlc-media/ 
networks:
        vlc_net:
```

But it is as if there was no network from the container of the other machine to my machine. I thought that putting it in bridge mode would solve it, but I saw that you can't put the Docker Swarm in bridge mode. I need to play the video on several machines on the network, does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Before you deploy the stack to the swarm, [create a Docker Network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) with the overlay driver (note that network names must be unique):

```sh
docker network create --driver overlay vlc_net
```

This will create an overlay network that spans the entire swarm.

Then try setting the network options like this:

```yaml
networks:
  vlc_net:
    driver: overlay
    external: true
```

It might also help you to look at how [Traefik](https://containo.us/traefik/) manages its network in a docker swarm and try to replicate it, since all containers in a swarm can connect to Traefik, and that seems like the use case you are trying to solve.

Comment: I tried and gave this error ```network "vlc_net" is declared as external, but could not be found. You need to create a swarm-scoped network before the stack is deployed ```